# What goes on in the background when we assign Object1 = Object2 of the same class in C++?

Tags: c++

Suppose that both the objects (of the same class) have been initialized already.

Now, you do:
**Object2 = Object1;**

In Java, what happens is that both Object1 and Object2 now point to the same memory location.

What happens in C++?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X {
    public:
        X() {
            cout << "Default Constructor called\n";
            i = 0;
        }
        X(int i) {
            cout << "Parameterized Constructor called\n";
            this->i = i;
        }
        X (const X& x) {
            cout << "Copy Constructor called\n";
            i = x.getI();
        }
        ~X() {
            cout << "Destructor called\n";
        }
        int getI() const {
            return i;
        }

    private:
        int i;
};

void main() {
    cout << "\nLine-1\n\n";
    X x1(1);    // On Stack
    cout << "\nLine-2\n\n";
    X* x2 = new X(2);   // On Heap
    cout << "\nLine-3\n\n";
    X x3(x1);
    cout << "\nLine-4\n\n";
    X* x4 = new X(x1);
    cout << "\nLine-5\n\n";
    X x5 = x1;
    cout << "\nLine-6\n\n";
    x5 = x3;
    cout << "\nLine-7\n\n";
    X x6 = *x2;
    cout << "\nLine-8\n\n";
    *x2 = *x4;
    cout << "\nLine-9\n\n";
    *x4 = x3;
    cout << "\nLine-10\n\n";

}
```

As you can see, whenever I do createdObj1 = createdObj2, none of the constructors is invoked.

Comment: How were they initialized? (e.g., with new, or are they stack allocated?)

Comment: On stack, my brother.

Comment: The copy assignment operator is invoked.  The compiler provides one by default.

Comment: @ Ben Voigt: Which takes us to the next question. I wrote my own copy constructor and had a print statement to know when it's invoked but it never got invoked.

Comment: `main()` shall return `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The function `operator=()` defines what happens. It can be defined as a member function, typically:

```
Object & Object::operator=(const Object &other);
```

If you do not provide one of these functions, a default implementation will be provided, which uses the `operator=()` function for each member variable.

Comment: `operator=` must be a member, period.

Answer (score 2):

Two major cases exist:

When performing an declaration with assignment, as in

```
X x = y;
```

it is usually (see the comment @T.C. made about explicit copy constructors) equivalent to

```
X x(y);
```

and thus will simply construct your new object in place. No assignment is done at all. This obviously creates a new object `x` which has automatic storage duration. (If I had written (`static X x = y;` it would have had static storage duration instead.)

The other case is

```
x = y;
```

where `x` is modified to equal `y`. This is done by calling `X::operator=(X)`, whose default implementation will simply assign each member in turn. (A custom version can do whatever it wants.)

Comment: Copy-initialization is in no way "exactly equivalent" to direct-initialization.

Comment: @T.C. It is, in this case: "If the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified
version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination,
constructors are considered. [...]"

Comment: @gha.st They are still not equivalent, due to the craziness known as explicit copy constructors.